# CSH input- to accept wilcard with getOptions without using \ -Perl

Tags: regex, perl, wildcard, csh

I am working with perl in csh. Now I am using get options thing. 
I want to use as

```
myperl -f temp1*.txt
```

But it won't go into code and give me error 'No match.'
Currently I below things are working..

```
myperl -f temp1\*.txt
```

and

```
myperl -f "temp1*.txt"
```

How to get first thing working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't work. The asterisk is a special char in shell. So you need to escape it anyway.

Most characters (`*`, `'`, etc) are not interpreted (ie, they are taken literally) by means of placing them in double quotes (`""`). They are taken as is and passed on to the command being called. An example using the asterisk (`*`) goes:

```
$ echo *
case.shtml escape.shtml first.shtml 
functions.shtml hints.shtml index.shtml 
ip-primer.txt raid1+0.txt
$ echo *txt
ip-primer.txt raid1+0.txt
$ echo "*"
*
$ echo "*txt"
*txt
```

[Source](http://steve-parker.org/sh/escape.shtml)

Comment: What I mean if if simply ls * is working without using '\\*'. Then it should work for temp*.txt, too, right?

Comment: Nope. Take a look [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62660/the-result-of-ls-ls-and-ls)

Comment: If `perl temp*.txt` fails then `ls temp*.txt` will also fail with the same error message. Repeat: the glob is expanded by the shell, your program doesn't run at all when the glob fails. (Bash has an option to change this; perhaps csh does, too?)

Comment: Actually myperl -f tmp*.txt is failing. Does it have something to do with when being used with options?

Comment: The point is, that you need to use one of your 2 last ways. The asterisk need to be escaped. But instead of using an asterisk, you can use another char which will be replaced in your script.

Comment: @karate_kid `ls` is designed to accept many inputs at once.  It is possible that `myperl` only expects one .  This would cause the discrepancy between the two programs.  The shell expands `*` *before* passing to the program *unless* it is escaped with the `\\` or with quotes.